# How to fix error installation module Open Cart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

When I try to upload module using Extension Installer in Open Cart I get an error.
See attachment:
[image]

I figure out that during installation ditrectories is created by the following path: `/system/storage/upload`.

With permissions:

```
0755
```

And owner: `apache:apache`

I assume that problem in ownership, because remaining directoties open cart have `root:root` permissions.

Additional screen with error:

[image]

Comment: do you have a root access from ssh ?

Comment: Yes I have  root ssh

Comment: so you have to edit all files and directpries permission with chmod -R 777